# Segmentation Fault - Why am I getting this error?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

The code seems to do everything it's supposed to do, but then it gives a segmentation fault at the end. I'm new to C so I'm not sure what's going on here.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

const char *fileName = "data.txt";

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *file = fopen(fileName, "r"); 
    int i, j;
    int temp;

    fscanf(file, "%d", &temp);
    const int tickNum = temp;
    fscanf(file, "%d", &temp);
    const int pNum = temp;

    struct data {
    int process, tau, tick;
    float alpha;
    int ticks[tickNum];

    };

    struct data *p[pNum];

    for(i = 0; i < pNum; i++) {
        fscanf(file, "%d %d %f", &p[i]->process, &p[i]->tau, &p[i]->alpha);
        for(j = 0; j < tickNum; j++) {
            fscanf(file, "%d", &p[i]->ticks[j]);
        }
    }
    fclose(file);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Comment: `p[i]->process` : You are using an unassigned pointer. `struct data *p[pNum];` --> `struct data *p = malloc(pNUM * sizeof(*p));`..`&p[i]->process` --> `&p[i].process`

Comment: Check the return value of `fopen` before using `file `

Comment: Have code check the return value of `fscanf()`.  E.g. `if (fscanf(file, "%d %d %f", &p[i]->process, &p[i]->tau, &p[i]->alpha) != 3) Exit_With_Error_Message();`

Comment: `struct data *p[pNum];` will initialize a **pointer**, not the struct itself. You really should do programming basics before you start trying yourself at algorithms ... it takes years of training.

Comment: You get the crash because you have *undefined behavior*. And you have *undefined behavior* because you use an array of pointers without making them actually *point* anywhere.

Comment: `struct data *p[pNum];` --> `struct data p[pNum];`, `&p[i]->process` --> `&p[i].process`

Comment: @specialist `struct data *p[pNum];` is __not__ initializing any pointer, nor a struct.

Comment: It's not permitted to have a VLA inside a struct; the line     `int ticks[tickNum];` should be rejected by the compiler.

Comment: If your compiler supports it, you can use a *Flexible Array Member* for `ticks`, e.g. `int ticks[]` which must be the *last* member of the struct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Where to start? There are a large number of problems you are dealing with. Some not all that trivial for a new C programmer. I'll address those that a new programmer should pay particular attention to, and then incorporate them into an example of how you can restructure your code to address the issues.

Let's take the declaration of `data` first. The problem you face is you do not know the value of `ticknum` beforehand. As all have noted in the comments and other answers, you cannot use a non-constant declaration of the number of elements in `ticks` within a struct declaration. No *Variable Length Arrays* (VLA)'s allowed. The problem being that the compiler will not know the `sizeof (struct data);` if it has a variable length object tacked onto the end making it impossible to do pointer arithmetic or array indexing on an array of `struct data`

Beginning with C99, C does provide the *Flexible Array Member* (FAM) allowing a single declaration of the *last member* as `int ticks[]` -- **however** you cannot create an array of `struct data` or include `struct data` within another struct or union if it includes a `FAM`. There is also the *zero length array -- struct hack* where `ticks` is declared as `int ticks[0];` which basically serves as a header for a VLA, but that also has similar inherent problems.

So how to handle this situation with `ticks` and `ticknum`? You have two choices. If you know `ticknum` cannot exceed a maximum value, you can declare a constant for the max value (e.g. `#define TICKNUM 32`) and then declare `ticks` as a statically declared array `int ticks[TICKNUM];` However, that is wasteful for all elements of `p` that have less than `TICKNUM` ticks. It can also exhaust your stack space if you have a large number of elements in your array of `struct data`.

Option number two is to declare `ticks` as a *pointer to int* (e.g. `int *ticks;`) and then dynamically allocate `ticks` separately within each of the `pnum` elements in your `p` array of `struct data`. Here you have the benefit of being able to exactly size your memory use for the `ticknum` read from the file, and since you dynamically allocate, the memory is allocated from the heap and is only limited by the memory you have available (handled by your OS's memory manager). This is the correct way to approach your problem, the only downside is the responsibility is placed on you to allocate for each `ticks` array, and then free each when you are done with them.

Next, while *style* is up to you, C traditionally avoids the use of `camelCase` or `MixedCase` variable names in favor of all *lower-case* while reserving *upper-case* names for use with macros and constants. (if you were wondering why I change your `pNum` and `tickNum` names...)

***Validate, validate, validate*** all *input* (especially *user input*), all *file writes*, all *memory allocations*, and all *file close* following file writes. If you read it, validate whatever function you used thinks it read what you expected it to read. All functions provide a **return**. Use them to minimally validate all inputs and conversions and memory allocations.

Unless you have a reason for declaring `data` within `main()` (which is fine, but...) generally you want your data types (e.g. `struct data {....};` declared with file scope so any functions you write, etc. have the type available for use. Standard C also provides that all declarations take place before you begin executing statements. Effectively the standard wants all variables declared at the beginning of each function (`main()` being a function). This is not always possible (or practical), but adhere to it to the greatest extent possible.

Always compile with **compiler warnings enabled**, at minimum `-Wall -Wextra` (or the equivalent for your compiler) and **do not** accept code until it compiles without warning. (you can learn as much C from reading, understanding and addressing all issues your compiler is telling you about as you can from any tutorial) If you had enabled and addressed the warnings, among them you would have found that the `tick` element of `data` was unused throughout your code.

Putting all of those pieces together, you could rearrange your code to work something similar to the following. (I didn't have example input, so I had to read-the-tea-leaves a bit)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct data {
    int process, tau /*, tick */;  /* tick unused in your code */
    float alpha;
    int *ticks;
};

int main (int argc, char** argv) {

    const char *filename = argc > 1 ? argv[1] : "data.txt";
    int ticknum = 0, pnum = 0;
    struct data *p = NULL;
    FILE *file = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    if (!file) {    /* validate file open for reading */
        fprintf (stderr, "error: file open failed '%s'.\n", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    /* validate ALL input */
    if (fscanf (file, "%d", &ticknum) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read failure - ticknum.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    if (fscanf (file, "%d", &pnum) != 1) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: read failure - pnum.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /* allocate and validate ALL memory allocations */
    if (!(p = malloc (sizeof *p * pnum))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pnum; i++) {
        if (fscanf (file, "%d %d %f", /* validate process, tau, alpha */
                    &p[i].process, &p[i].tau, &p[i].alpha) != 3) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: read failure process[%d].\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        /* allocate/validate p[i].ticks */
        if (!(p[i].ticks = malloc (sizeof *p->ticks * ticknum))) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: memory exhausted p[%d].ticks.\n", i);
            return 1;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < ticknum; j++) {     /* validate ticks[j] */
            if (fscanf (file, "%d", &p[i].ticks[j]) != 1) {
                fprintf (stderr, "error: read failure process[%d].ticks[%d].\n", 
                        i, j);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    fclose (file);

    for (int i = 0; i < pnum; i++) {    /* output data */
        printf ("%2d  %8d    %8d    %.3f\n", 
                i, p[i].process, p[i].tau, p[i].alpha);
        for (int j = 0; j < ticknum; j++)
            printf ("  ticks[%2d] : %d\n", j, p[i].ticks[j]);
        free (p[i].ticks);  /* free p[i].ticks memory */
    }

    free (p);   /* free allocated memory for p */

    return 0;
}
```

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat dat/ticks.dat
6 3
8152 1123 123.456
 1 3 5 7 9 11
8153 2123 124.567
 2 4 6 8 10 12
8154 3123 125.678
 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/ticks dat/ticks.dat
 0      8152        1123    123.456
  ticks[ 0] : 1
  ticks[ 1] : 3
  ticks[ 2] : 5
  ticks[ 3] : 7
  ticks[ 4] : 9
  ticks[ 5] : 11
 1      8153        2123    124.567
  ticks[ 0] : 2
  ticks[ 1] : 4
  ticks[ 2] : 6
  ticks[ 3] : 8
  ticks[ 4] : 10
  ticks[ 5] : 12
 2      8154        3123    125.678
  ticks[ 0] : 1
  ticks[ 1] : 2
  ticks[ 2] : 3
  ticks[ 3] : 4
  ticks[ 4] : 5
  ticks[ 5] : 6
```

**Memory Use/Error Check**

It is imperative that you use a memory error checking program to insure you do not attempt to write beyond/outside the bounds of your allocated block of memory, attempt to read or base a conditional jump on an uninitialized value, and finally, to confirm that you free all the memory you have allocated.

For Linux `valgrind` is the normal choice. There are similar memory checkers for every platform. They are all simple to use, just run your program through it.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/ticks dat/ticks.dat
==6270== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==6270== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==6270== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==6270== Command: ./bin/ticks dat/ticks.dat
==6270==
 0      8152        1123    123.456
  ticks[ 0] : 1
  ticks[ 1] : 3
  ticks[ 2] : 5
  ticks[ 3] : 7
  ticks[ 4] : 9
  ticks[ 5] : 11
 1      8153        2123    124.567
  ticks[ 0] : 2
  ticks[ 1] : 4
  ticks[ 2] : 6
  ticks[ 3] : 8
  ticks[ 4] : 10
  ticks[ 5] : 12
 2      8154        3123    125.678
  ticks[ 0] : 1
  ticks[ 1] : 2
  ticks[ 2] : 3
  ticks[ 3] : 4
  ticks[ 4] : 5
  ticks[ 5] : 6
==6270==
==6270== HEAP SUMMARY:
==6270==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==6270==   total heap usage: 5 allocs, 5 frees, 696 bytes allocated
==6270==
==6270== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==6270==
==6270== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

Always confirm that you have freed all memory you have allocated and that there are no memory errors.

Look things over and let me know if you have any further questions. Good luck with your coding.

Answer (score 1):

`*p[pNum]` is only a field of individual pointers to not yet existing instances of `struct data` the way you have written it. It does not actually point to a valid memory regions yet, so accessing it causes a memory access violation.

Get rid of the excess `*` to turn into a stack allocation instead, or allocate instance on the heap with `malloc`. You will also need to modify the syntax of your calls to `scanf` in the first case, and get used to using braces when using `&` and `->` in the same term, in order to avoid confusing yourself about the order in which it is resolved.

You also might actually have intended to write `(*p)[pNum]` instead, which would have been a single pointer to a field of structs instead.

In fact, you should also turn up the warning level of your compiler, because it should have complained violently already. Adding `-Wall -Werror -Wextra -pedantic` to the compiler command line is a good start.

Comment: Haven't heard anybody calling an "array" a "field" since decades ...:-)

Answer (score 1):

At this line:

```
struct data *p[pNum];
```

You declarate an array that will contain pointers to initalized structs,
but initially there's no initialized structs and the pointers are pointed to "nowhere", you should create structs and pointer them manually, like this way:

```
for (i = 0; i < pNum, i++) {
    p[i] = malloc(sizeof(struct data));
}
```

Answer (score -1):

As suggested by others the pointers are looking into invalid memory area, allocate memory for struct variables to get rid of Segmentation Fault ,i  would suggest something like below.

```
struct data **p=malloc(pNum*sizeof *p);
for (i=0;i<pNum;i++){
    p[i]=malloc(sizeof p);
}
```

Comment: Where the OPs needs any 2D stuff? Also what you show is not the creating of a 2D-array, but of jagged array, consisting of 1+pNum 1D arrays.